# Disable XP disk check using FAT32

Tags: boot, windows-xp, boot-camp, check-disk

Right now I'm using Windows XP and Macintosh on my MacBook Pro via Bootcamp. Sometimes my XP would crash and when I restarted it it would have to go through disk check, although it says I can skip it by pushing a key, but this never worked for me. I did a bit of research online on how to disable disk check and found **chkntfs /x c:** but when I tried this out in my cmd it said the disk is FAT32 format. I tried to convert my C: drive from FAT32 to NTFS by using **convert c: /FS:NTFS** but when I tried this it told me to locate my C: drive. I tried to type C: and Bootcamp but couldn't really get past it. I later saw someone said to use this:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager]
>   "AutoChkTimeOut"=dword:0000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager]
>   "BootExecute"=hex(7):61,00,75,00,74,00,6f,00,63,00,68,00,65,00,63,00,6b,00,20,\
>   00,61,00,75,00,74,00,6f,00,63,00,68,00,6b,00,20,00,2a,00,00,00,00,00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] "SFCScan"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\cleanuppath]
>   @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
>   00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,63,00,6c,00,\
>   65,00,61,00,6e,00,6d,00,67,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2f,00,44,\
>   00,20,00,25,00,63,00,00,00 (Save it as .reg and execute it)

I have just tried running it but am not really sure if it did anything (my laptop hasn't crashed yet :) )

Firstly, I am wondering if someone can tell me how to check if that script worked? Secondly, if that script didn't work, does anyone have any solution for these problems? Is there another way to disable disk check or is there another way for me to change my FAT32 to NTFS?

Comment: The commands you used should work.  You do understand support for NTFS is very limited on OS X right?

Comment: Windows isn't natively FAT32 - so next time you install Windows via Bootcamp I'd use the Windows Partition Manager utility during installation to change the partition to NTFS - Second, you can't convert a LIVE disk from FAT32 to NTFS... it has to be offline.

Comment: @ekaj, so is it possible for me to convert my c drive to NTFS? And my disk check takes over half an hour to complete that's why I want to skip it.

Comment: I do not believe so since your system is already running - I could be wrong, though, but it seems to me that you shouldn't be able to convert a file system to a different type once it is already in use

Comment: hmmm, I see. next time when I reinstall my windows I'l make sure to do it in NTFS then.